# How to get MDC context in reactive calls

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive, mdc

I've followed the method shared in [this repo](https://github.com/archie-swif/webflux-mdc/) to attach MDC information to logs in a reactive Spring Boot 3 application, but in [my toy application](https://github.com/spartanhooah/reactive-logging-demo) when I try to use `contextWrite` to add an `"mdc"` context item, I don't see it in the logs. If I set a breakpoint [in the MdcContextLifter(https://github.com/spartanhooah/reactive-logging-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/MdcContextLifter.java#L54) I *do* see my `"mdc"` context key go through the lambdas. What would be preventing it from getting from there to the actual logs?